# Generate a "graphic method references chart" for a Java project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to analyze a big Java project (actually an Android project). I would like to know if there is a way to generate a visual tree of references between methods calls. 
In Eclipse I can see the references between methods with "Call hierarchy" function (Ctrl+Alt+H). Is there a way to do it on the entire project and show the result as a graphic chart, i.e. a tree?

Comment: It's not a tree, it's a graph; some methods may call each other.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, if you right-click on any method in the package explorer, you can choose References -> Workspace to see all references to that method.

Comment: Ok, but this is limited to a single method. I'd like to have all references between all methods shown at the same time...

Comment: For any real project, that would become unreadable and would require tons of memory.  I think the closest you can get is a class diagram showing the relationships between classes.  That will at least show "USES" relationships if a method is called between them.